# Update row with another query result

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a database set up like this, I want to move Milk to the end by changing the priority to the last number + 1.

```
id | item | priority
---|------|----------   
[...]
26 | Milk | 1
27 | Eggs | 2
28 | Ham  | 3
```

So I need to run something like this

```
UPDATE shopping SET priority = (SELECT priority FROM shopping ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1) + 1 WHERE id = '26'
```

and end up with something like this

```
id | item | priority
---|------|----------   
[...]
27 | Eggs | 2
28 | Ham  | 3
26 | Milk | 4
```

How to I go about doing this *correctly*?

Comment: The `LIMIT` probably won't work in that subquery. You can use `SELECT MAX(priority) + 1 FROM shopping` as the subquery, but this is not immune to race conditions!

Comment: do `eggs` and `ham` would increase their priority as well?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski "Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0" - Worked great, Guess I've learnt something new today. You should enter this as an answer so I can mark you as correct!

Comment: @JohnWoo, The starting number of the priority doesn't matter, only that the next item is the next number if sorted lowest to highest.

Comment: @JamieTaylor And do you know what he means with "not immune to race conditions"? That's the important part to learn here.

Comment: @tombom I don't D: Was about to google it, anything you could suggest looking for specifically?

Comment: @JamieTaylor The race condition in my suggestion would be a situation when two clients attempt this update at the same time. If they both retrieve the initial `MAX()+1` value at the same time but one completes the update first, the second will update to the old, now incorrect value of `MAX()+1`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ahh, I see, although this may become an issue with some tables needing unique IDs, it's not a big deal if I have 2 records with priority 4 as everything will end up getting processed in the end anyway. I can see why I should look at it though when working with anything which isn't so flexible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `shopping` s, (
    SELECT
        MAX(`priority`) AS 'maxPriority',
        MAX(`id`) AS 'maxId'
    FROM `shopping`
) t
SET
    s.`priority` = t.`maxPriority` + 1,
    s.`id` = t.`maxId` + 1
WHERE s.`id`=26
AND s.`priority` != t.`maxPriority`
# this ensures that it's not the one that's
# already holding the max priority
```

Answer (score 0):

your request could be:

```
UPDATE shopping SET priority = (select max(priority)+1) where id=26;
```

But this will not working, you must make same changes to the request, source and details here:

http://the-stickman.com/uncategorized/mysql-update-with-select-on-the-same-table-in-the-same-query/